# Add dlls in .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

We can define relative or absolute path below the reference like this:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>   
    <OutputPath>..\..\bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
 </PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
<Reference Include="customdll1">
   <HintPath>..\..\bin\x64\Release\custom1.dll</HintPath>
</Reference
<Reference Include="customdll2">
   <HintPath>..\..\bin\x64\Release\custom2.dll</HintPath>
</Reference
............
```

Is there anyway we can globally define the dlls path? Here I need to manually define the dlls path each time.

Comment: sure just code in msbuild variables. however you should consider using package references

Comment: Hi @DanielA.White 
Could you please share some piece of code. it will help me to understand your points.

Comment: For [`defining the dlls globally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022#define-and-reference-properties-in-a-project-file)  you can have a look at this [`official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022)